# More pythonic way to write this?

Tags: python

I have this code here:

```
import re
def get_attr(str, attr):
    m = re.search(attr + r'=(\w+)', str)
    return None if not m else m.group(1)

str = 'type=greeting hello=world'

print get_attr(str, 'type')   # greeting    
print get_attr(str, 'hello')  # world
print get_attr(str, 'attr')   # None
```

Which works, but I am not particularly fond of this line:

```
return None if not m else m.group(1)
```

In my opinion this would look cleaner if we could use a ternary operator:

```
return (m ? m.group(1) : None)
```

But that of course isn't there. What do you suggest?

Comment: `None if not m else m.group(1)` **is** the Python equivalent to `m ? m.group(1) : None`!

Comment: @delnan I know. It just doesn't strike as particularly readable to me; maybe I am too used to the "regular" ternary operator. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: What makes `?` and `:` more readable than `if .. else` ? You can actually read that line out loud!

Comment: It seems like the only advantage in your preferred ternary syntax is order, so why not just use that order in python, i.e. return m.group(1) if m else None? Sure seems easier to follow to me than c-style ternary syntax. Perhaps you were thinking the first return value would get evaluated before the conditional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python *has* a ternary operator.  You're using it.  It's just in the `X if Y else Z` form.

That said, I'm prone to writing these things out.  Fitting things on one line isn't so great if you sacrifice clarity.

```
def get_attr(str, attr):
    m = re.search(attr + r'=(\w+)', str)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)

    return None
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use:

```
return m.group(1) if m else m
```

It's explicit, and you don't have to do any logic puzzles to understand it :)

Comment: How is that more explicit than return None? Who knows what `m` is there? What if m is actually '' or 0 or some custom class that evaluates to False

Answer (score 3):

```
return m and m.group(1)
```

would be one Pythonic way to do it.

If `m` is `None` (or something else that evaluates "falsely"), it returns `m`, but if `m` is "true-ish", then it returns `m.group(1)`.

Comment: I feel like this is trying to be too hard to be clever.

Comment: Actually, if expressions have superseded the clever use of the fact that boolean operators return their operands.

Comment: Agreed.  It works, but it kind of feels like an abuse of the `and` operator.  Oddly, I don't feel the same way about the `or` operator (e.g. `return x or 'NO VALUE'`)

Comment: To me it looks much more "perlish" than pythonic. (i.e. too much idiomatic)

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is python's conditional operator. IMO it's perfectly pythonic as-is and needs no change. Remember, `explicit is better than implicit`. What you have now is readable and instantly understandable.